# How to judge NSEvent from trackpad click, not tap to click

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsevent

When "tap to click" checked, how judge NSEvent is from trackpad click(pressed down) or tap to click.

```
- (void)mouseEvent:(NSEvent*)theEvent {
  if ((type == NSLeftMouseUp || type == NSLeftMouseDown) && [theEvent subtype] == NSEventSubtypeTouch) {
    // How to detect touchpad is real pressed?? Not tap to cllick
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To find out if someone only "tap to click" you could use

```
func pressureChange(with event: NSEvent)
```

in your NSViewController on NSView.

If someone only "tap" the function will not be triggered. In case of a click you will get the pressure level on pressure change.

```
   override func pressureChange(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.pressureChange(with: event)
        print("pressure \(event.pressure)")
    }
```

Comment: Mac os in objective -c?

Comment: trackpad press down, this function not called.

Comment: - (void)pressureChangeWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_10_3);  in NSResponder, not NSViewController

Comment: It is not force touch trackpad

Comment: It is only useful for force touch trackpad

Comment: Yes, you are right. It will work only with force touch trackpads but I assume most MacBooks nowadays will have one.

Comment: only after 2016 macbook has force touch trackpad